# How can I grant permission to a user to change the IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, ifconfig

I need the user be able to change the IP address, without giving him full super user access. How can I do that?

I tried the solution here https://serverfault.com/a/480823
That works fine, but only once, then I have to redo these steps again.

How can I grant the user permission to change the IP address whenever he feels like to?

**Edit:** I did not `rm` the file, as outlined in the link above. But when I try it again, I get errors like

```
SIOCSIFADDR: Permission denied
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Permission denied
SIOCSIFNETMASK: Permission denied
SIOCSIFBROADCAST: Permission denied
```

just as if I used `ifconfig` directly.

Comment: The last step in that [serverfault suggestion](http://serverfault.com/a/480823) is to delete the modified `ifconfig`. If you avoided doing that you wouldn't need to repeat any of the earlier preparation steps. Would this be acceptable?

Comment: Does your distribution have a special group for network management? Add the user to the group? Or use `sudo`?

Comment: @roaima I did not use `rm` to remove the file. But it stops working for me.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky That is the solution that I'm looking for, but I don't know what group to use.

Comment: You haven't told us what distribution you use, so we have no way of knowing that group (if any) you could add the user to. Please provide ud with complete in-and output from the command that work and the one that doesn't.

Comment: I'm using Scientific Linux 6.

Comment: Will that user be logged in on the console? If so, tell them to use NetworkManager.

Comment: @Gilles The user will be logged in, but he need to be able to control the IP on the command line. Can this be done with `nmcli`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy way to change ip address is on the command line with `ifconfig`

```
# ifconfig   <interface>   <ipaddress>   netmask  <netmask>

  sudo /sbin/ifconfig  192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

# for changing gateway if desired

  sudo /sbin/route add default gw 192.168.0.253 eth0
```

you edit the sudoers file using `visudo`

**Option 1**: create a new group, called *ipchangers* for example.  Then in visudo append at the bottom of file

```
%ipchangers ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig
%ipchangers ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/route       {if desired}
```

be sure to instruct your *ipchangers* users that they have to type `sudo /sbin/ifconfig`.  And you add all users to the *ipchangers* group you wish to have ability to run `ifconfig`

**Option 2**: do it for just a specific user(s) *joe* and *jack* for example, you do it without the %

```
john   ALL=NOPASSWD:  /sbin/ifconfig
jack   ALL=NOPASSWD:  /sbin/ifconfig
```

when exiting `visudo` it should cleanly exit.  If not and it gives something like

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 57 <<<
What now?
```

then your syntax is wrong.  follow the subsequent instructions and correct the syntax, don't save a bad sudoers file.

Be aware whoever you grant ability to run `ifconfig` is allowed to use `ifconfig` o its fullest extent and can do more than just change ip address with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you skip the command `rm ifconfig` (last line in the solution you linked) you should be good to go.
But leaving a command like `ifconfig` for a non-sysadmin to use all the time, unsupervised, is a security nightmare. He may not be malicious but if something happens and someone else gets hold of this account, well, you can guess the badlam they can cause.
Just a word of caution.

Comment: Fix the the group and permissions. Or use `sudo` (without the _capability_)

Comment: I did not `rm` the file. I edited the question.